# How to convert Entity Bean to Value Object?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I am developing an Server System providing services for both Client and Browser, I decided to use JPA dealing with OR/Mapping for DB storage. This leads to Entity Bean class exposed to the client, I therefore try to avoid such design by using Value Object and Data Transfer Objects. That means I need POJO, and mechanisms to interchange POJO and Entity Bean classes at different system tires.

My question is, Is there any mature design pattern or EJB specified service can do this automatically? I really hate to design some POJO - Entity Bean one-to-one mapping which is hard to decouple and update.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

> This leads to Entity Bean class
>   exposed to the client, I therefore try to avoid such design by using Value Object and Data Transfer Objects.

Why? What is the problem that justifies such atrocious code duplication?

"Data Transfer Object" and the wrong use of the "Value Object" name are antipatterns that were necessary with EJB 2 Entity Beans to avoid excessive server roundtrips.

If you use JPA, you don't *have* entity beans. Your entities *are* POJOs, and there is absolutely nothing wrong with exposing them to the client - in fact that's one of the best things about JPA.

Comment: Yes, I have to admit I raised a pretty bad question. I am new to EJB. thanks for your information.

Comment: Because the view should not have to know every entity or database table that it is based on. So that if you change your method of persistence you don't have to rewrite your user interface. The same reason you abstract your database calls with O/R mapping.

Comment: @BillR: *of course* your view has to know about the entities it's based on, otherwise it can't do anything. And it's not as if the view is going to accidentally use reflection to access the JPA annotations and rely on them. Funny that you should mention O/R-mapping - that's what JPA is. So the "change the DB mid-project" case is already covered - although that never really happens and certainly is not the main reason why one uses OR mappers. They are used to avoid writing lots of repetitive CRUD code.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt I think this is a naive view and will lead to problems in maintaining an app in the future (say in 10 years or more). This is why facades etc are used. So the view doesn't need to know about the database, so you reduce the number of remote calls in cases where multiple tables are used, and so the view doesn't have to know the business logic, which the database and entities are much closer to. If all you are doing are trivial single server apps with little business logic your way might work. For any significant business application it is in my opinion, wrong. Regards.

Comment: @BillR: I think you're misunderstanding me. I am not proposing the view to get those JPA entities directly from the persistence layer. Of course there should be a service layer of appropriate granularity. But it's perfectly OK for that service layer to return objects graphs that contain those JPA entities. Creating an entire duplicate model that the entities are mapped to just to avoid the JPA annotations being visible outside the persistence layer is a bad case of YAGNI and will lead to its own set of very severe maintenance problems.

Comment: Granularity is something I look at. Another is that tables updated (often indirectly) by the client, often have more fields than the client needs to know. Personally, I won't give a client the option to update a field in an entity object that might impact data it shouldn't even know about. You can also call this granularity, but I think of it as a form of encapsulation. For example, say a user's credit level field in an entity should not be (even implied to be) updatable by the client, since business rules in the model are responsible for that. Access modifiers also cause extra code. :)

Comment: @BillR: now you're talking about security-relevant applications with fat clients running in untrusted environments or huge SOA-based application landscapes. That changes the game completely. Most applications aren't like that, and shouldn't be designed as if they were (YAGNI again). In the rare case a typical inventory or workflow app evolves into something like that, you can add extra layers at that point.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt There are people who mostly/only/ever deal/dealt with these kinds of apps. To them this isn't so rare. I'm one of those. :) Regardless, I believe all apps should be security conscious. Then we wouldn't hear about as many security related incidents. As mentioned, access modifiers also increase the amount of code we need. By your logic all member variables should be public and allow open access to them, as in most cases this wouldn't cause a problem. But we know that would be a bad habit to get into. To me this is no different. Looking at various forums I see I'm not alone. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/), a bean mapper that uses reflection to map beans based on field names. It gives you some protection against changes because you can always specify mappings manually if one class changes but you want to keep the mapped class the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help, artbristol, I am now learning Dozer to see if that fits my need. Meanwhile, I am think about JavaCompiler and Reflection to do all stuff dynamically :)